# Angular 4 form validation

Tags: forms, angular, validation

How to validate a form in angular 4 by clicking on external link (ie out side from tag). If the form is valid do some actions with form data else show validation messages. If form is valid I don't want to submit the form just need to get the form field values.

Comment: check this links [reactive](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/reactive), [template](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template)

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer post to another question:

The easy way is to use reactive forms, like this:

Code:

```
 import {ReactiveForm, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/form';
    export class SignupFormComponent implements OnInit {
      userForm: FormGroup;
      firstName: string;

      constructor(private _formBuilder:FormBuilder){}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.userForm = this._formBuilder.group({
          'firstName': ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)]]
        });
      }

      onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.firstName);
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
     <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" name="userForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
            <p *ngIf="userForm.controls.firstName.invalid && (userForm.controls.firstName.dirty || userForm.controls.firstName.touched)"> Error message </p>
          </div>
          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="userForm.invalid">Submit </button>
        </form>
```